# How to set a tkinter windows on top when running a slide app (e.g. Keynote)

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, tkinter

I want to show some dynamic text in a window on top when playing a slide show in fullscreen mode. I use the OS X.

I had tried the method attributes("-topmost", 1). Not work...

Thanks

Here is my code:

```
# coding=utf-8                                                                                                 

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title(u"弾幕")
root.attributes("-alpha", 0.3)
root.attributes("-topmost", 1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you paste some code you have worked on ?

Comment: Excuse me, I am new to here. I'll append my code soon, and I am in class now. Thanks.